# Is there any free tool to generate a tone with gradually increasing pitch?

Tags: pitch

I need to generate a tone with a gradually increasing pitch with a very slow ratio. That is, I need a sine/square/sawtooth tone (amplitude doesn't matter) starting from 20Hz and gradually, linearly (or exponentially) increasing to 16kHz over 10 minute period. I need it to test a very specific audio device.

This seems like a simple task, yet I cannot find any free tool which would generate such a tone and save it to WAV or something like that. I tried fiddling with Audacity, but either I cannot find it or such tone not possible to achieve in it.

Does anybody know any free tool which would help me in generating such tone?

Comment: I'm just intrigued as to the device :-)

Comment: Octave and Python are some alternatives too from what has already been suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does almost everything you need (save for the length): http://heliso.tripod.com/download/generator/dsg.htm

Another one, also with a length limitation: http://softsolutions.sedutec.de/multisine.php

If you use a linear sweep, you can simply divide your 10 minutes into whatever is possible with the above tools and then splice the sound together in Audacity afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, the Multisine tool is exactly what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Audacity can do this. Select [**Generate → Chirp...**](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/chirp.html).

[image: Chirp Waveform Sine from 20 Hz to 16,000 Hz]

The default sampling frequency is 44.1 kHz, which can be adjusted under [**Edit → Preferences... → Quality → Sampling → Default Sample Rate**](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/quality_preferences.html)

[image: Default sample rate set to 44100 Hz]

Be careful not to hurt your ears when playing it back!

Answer (score 2):

The [`sox` utility](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) can do this. To generate a WAV file:

```
sox -n output.wav synth 600 sine 20-16k
```

Mind you, this will generate a 100 MB WAV file, since it defaults to a 48 kHz sampling rate. Since you need a maximum frequency of 16 kHz, you could get away with a 32 kHz sampling frequency instead:

```
sox -r 32k -n output.wav synth 600 sine 20-16k
```

This file will be only 74M. Or you could use MP3 and get it down to 3.5 MB:

```
sox -r 32k -n output.mp3 synth 600 sine 20-16k
```

A breakdown of how this works:

- The `-r 32k` specifies the 32 kHz sampling rate.
- The `-n output.wav` specifies the output filename.
- `600` is for 600 seconds (10 minutes).
- The `20-16k` is the frequency range (20 Hz to 16,000 Hz).

If you just want to play it directly, you can do this:

```
play -n synth 600 sine 20-16k
```

More information here:

- http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html
- http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Readme
- http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Features